# How do you mount a specific btrfs subvolume? (not via fstab)

Tags: mount, btrfs

I just can't figure out how to do this and there doesn't seem to be a single explanation about this; except the fstab case (here on stackexchange, but sadly I'm not allowed to add a comment) My only idea is (and that doesn't work):

```
mount --subvol=@foo /dev/sda1 /mnt/foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct commandline is

```
mount -o subvol=foo /dev/sda1 /mnt/foo
```

Comment: Okay, that "-o optionsstring" was not documented very prominently where i had looked. Also, subvolid=### worked more reliably for me than "subvol" (but that is stated everywhere).